# Connecting two 1Gb switches 100ft apart via 10Gb SFP

Tags: cisco

I need to connect two suites in the same building that will be about 100ft from data room to data room.
Suite #1 has a 1Gb switch and our various servers etc are connected to this switch
Suite #2 ( new office) will need a switch.

So basically I will be connecting switch #1 to switch #2. I realize I will probably need to buy a new switch #1, as the current switch has only 1Gb ports. We need 10Gb switch-switch total bandwidth - we often are shuffling large amounts of scientific data by multiple people at once to/from servers.

I was looking at , say, two of "ZyXEL 24-Port GbE Smart Managed Switch with 10GbE uplink SFP Ports" , and connecting the two switches via the 10Gb uplink port.

My question is, how do I physically connect the switches? Do the SFP ports support standard "Cat 6" cabling? i had already take cat 6 cables form [10Gtek](http://www.10gtek.com) Or do I need to run 100ft of fiber? What "extra" hardware might I need beyond just the switches?

Thanks!

Comment: SFP is (99%) used for optical cables. At your distance it is no problem at all to link the switches using 10GbE. Be aware that you usually need SFP or SFP+ modules for fibre. The switch you listed doesn't support 10GbE via copper by the looks of it. If you find another one: 10GbE needs Cat.6a for 100m, so at your distance Cat.6 could suffice, the price difference is negligible, though.

Comment: Skip your Zyxel and look at Mikrotik for cheap decent switches. Heck, you may upgrade to 10g for the servers in general - the networkcards EACH will be more expensive than a 16 port switch (no joke, that one is 400 USD).

Comment: SFP+ Copper Transceiver 10GBase-T, Cat 6a/7, 30M  can it work, i find on sfpcables

Answer (score 1):

SFP *ports* themselves don't support any cabling, it is actually the [SFP+ transceivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_form-factor_pluggable_transceiver#10_Gbit/s_SFP+) (that you will  need to buy separately and plug in the switch ports) that determine which cabling you can use.

10GBASE-T transceivers that can be used with existing RJ45 copper cables do exist and would work on the distance you need.

But if you need to pull new cabling, by far and large people use fiber with 10Gb